# Contextual text processing

Tags: command-line

I would classify my mathematics pdf collection in folders named by the [MSC 2010 Classification](https://cran.r-project.org/web/classifications/MSC-2010.html) (just the 2 top-level). My approach is creating a file which will contain all path and uses `mkdir` in a shell loop.

I clean the data then my file has the following content :

```
00-XX_General
    00Axx_General_and_miscellaneous_specific_topics
    00Bxx_Conference_proceedings_and_collections_of_papers
01-XX_History_and_biography
    01Axx_History_of_mathematics_and_mathematicians
03-XX_Mathematical_logic_and_foundations
    03Axx_Philosophical_aspects_of_logic_and_foundations
    03Bxx_General_logic
...    ...
```

How could I transform it to

```
00-XX_General
00-XX_General/00Axx_General_and_miscellaneous_specific_topics
00-XX_General/00Bxx_Conference_proceedings_and_collections_of_papers
01-XX_History_and_biography
01-XX_History_and_biography/01Axx_History_of_mathematics_and_mathematicians
03-XX_Mathematical_logic_and_foundations
03-XX_Mathematical_logic_and_foundations/03Axx_Philosophical_aspects_of_logic_and_foundations
03-XX_Mathematical_logic_and_foundations/03Bxx_General_logic
...    ...
```

in vim via command-line mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be accomplished using only `:substitute`:

`:%s/^\([^ /]\+\).*\n\zs\s\+/\1\/`

Here is a breakdown and some intuition on how I created this:

1. `:%s/` substitute on all lines. *subtlety*: this relies on vim processing the substitutes in order, so the initial part of the previous line continues to get captured.  I first created this without `%` and ensure it worked for one line.
2. `^\([^ /]\+\).*\n` match anything at the beginning of the line which is not space or `/`, capturing the characters, anything but newline, then finally a newline.  The key here is you can have matches which wrap to the following lines.
3. `\zs` starting match (i.e., replacement) here.  What comes after this will be what we actually want to replace.
4. `\s\+/\1\/` any number (at least 1) of spaces, replacing this with what we captured (stored in `\1`) followed by a `/`

This can be made a bit shorter by using `\v` (very magic) and also by changing `/` to `,`:

`:%s,\v^([^ /]+).*\n\zs\s+,\1/`

Comment: @user852573, your valid solution demonstrated a much more powerful approach (namely `g/re/cmd`), which may be useful in slightly different situations.

Comment: @PeterRincker thanks, added.  Actually `\S` was wrong in my original attempt, because it matched too much from the previous line (only need up to any `/`s).

Comment: Thank you @Mass, I didn't know `\zs` before! Though the deleted answer is a bit longer, it's what I used firstly. I think that it still worth to have multiple choice.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure this is exactly what you want but you could try this command:

```
sil exe 'g/^\s\+/s:^\s\+:/:|?^\S?t.-|j!|s/^/ /' | %s/^\s/
```

Broken down:

```
               ┌ every time you find a line beginning with a sequence of whitespace
           ┌───┤
           │   │          ┌ put a slash at the end of it
           │   │ ┌────────┤
           │   │ │        │        ┌ then find the previous line which doesn't begin with a whitespace
           │   │ │        │ ┌──────┤ and duplicate it above
           │   │ │        │ │      │
sil exe 'g/^\s\+/s:^\s\+:/:|?^\S?t.-|j!|s/^/ /' | %s/^\s/
                                     ││ │    │    └─────┤
                                     ││ │    │          └ remove a space at the beginning of any line
                                     ││ └────┤
                                     ││      └ add a space in front of the line
                                     └┤
                                      └ join it with the next line
```

---

Edit:

[Peter Rincker](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/13729/contextual-text-processing#comment23561_13731) has a much shorter solution:

```
v/^[^ /]\+$/??t-|norm! Js/
```

Here's how it works:

```
^[^ /]\+$
```

This pattern describes a line which doesn't contain any space nor slash (see `:h /^`, `:h /$`, `:h /[]`, `:h /\+`). If you could replace this pattern with the name `pat`, then you could rewrite the previous command like this:

```
v/pat/??t-|norm! Js/
```

This global command tries to find all the lines for which `pat` is NOT a valid description. See `:h :v`.

In your example, the following line satisfies this condition:

```
00Axx_General_and_miscellaneous_specific_topics
```

For this line, and any other line satisfying the same condition, `:v` executes this command:

```
??t-|norm! Js/
```

The bar is a separation between 2 commands, which are executed consecutively:

```
??t-
norm! Js/
```

To understand the 1st command, you must know that all Ex commands may be prefixed by a range, which limits their effect to a certain area of the buffer.
Here the Ex command is `:t`, and `??` is the range. `-` is just an argument passed to `:t`.

`:t` copies/duplicates a line or a group of lines below another arbitrary line.
Here, it copies the line specified by `??`. This line specifier is described in `:h range`: it matches the previous line containing the last search pattern. In your case, the last search pattern is:

```
^[^ /]\+$
```

So, this command:

```
??t-
```

… is the same as this one:

```
?^[^ /]\+$?t-
```

And it means: *find the previous line which does NOT contain a space or a slash and copy it below the line just above me*.

Why *just above me*?
Because `-` is another kind of line specifier. It's a shorthand for `.-1`, which stands for the line whose address is equal to the one of the current line (`.`) minus `1` (`-1`).

`-1` is a numerical offset. And any numerical offset may be used to tweak a valid line specifier. You can express a numerical offset with a sign (`-` or `+`) followed by a number, or by piling up `-` / `+` signs:

```
-3    ⇔    ---
+4    ⇔    ++++
```

In a line specifier, you can also omit the dot, so all of these expressions are equivalent:

```
.-1    ⇔    .-    ⇔    -
```

And in the same way, all of these expressions should be equivalent:

```
.+3    ⇔    .+++    ⇔    +++
```

So, going back to the line:

```
00Axx_General_and_miscellaneous_specific_topics
```

When `:v` finds it, it executes `??t-`. Then `:t` searches for the previous line which doesn't contain any space nor slash. And `:t` finds this line:

```
00-XX_General
```

Finally `:t` copies the line just above the current one:

```
00Axx_General_and_miscellaneous_specific_topics
```

Which performs the following transformation:

```
00-XX_General                                           00-XX_General
    00Axx_General_and_miscellaneous_specific_topics  →  00-XX_General
                                                        00Axx_General_and_miscellaneous_specific_topics
```

This should explain the 1st command, executed by `:v` every time it finds a line which doesn't contain a space nor a slash.

Now, for the 2nd command:

```
norm! Js/
```

This should type the 3 keys `Js/` in normal mode. `J` will join the line which has just been duplicated and the current line, performing this transformation:

```
00-XX_General                                       00-XX_General
00-XX_General                                    →  00-XX_General 00Axx_General_and_miscellaneous_specific_topics
00Axx_General_and_miscellaneous_specific_topics
```

Finally, `s/` will delete the character under the cursor and insert a slash.
As a result, it will replace the space right after `General` with a slash.

Note that the whole command will probably not work as expected if one of your lines contains a slash.
Also, the bang after `:normal` is important. Unless you really want the keys to be remapped, always add a bang.

For example, if you use [vim-sneak](https://github.com/justinmk/vim-sneak), your `s` key will probably be remapped to do something entirely different than what it does by default. Usually, you don't want a plugin or a custom mapping to interfere, so it's a good habit to always add a bang after `:normal`.

Comment: A little shorter: `:v/^[^ /]\+$/??t-|norm Js/`

Comment: Thank you @user852573! I'm just curious, did you format manually the explanation or there is another magic way?

Comment: @F. Martin, I imagine they used `:set virtualedit=all` and then just put in the comments. See `:h 'virtualedit'`

Comment: @PeterRincker Thanks! I didn't know this one either…

Comment: @F.Martin I use this plugin: https://github.com/lacygoill/vim-breakdown. But it doesn't have any documentation, and it's not finished, so I don't know whether it would work for you. If you want to try it, all you need to know is some mappings. Namely `m Enter` (mark a character), `m C-h` (cancel marking), `m(`, `m)`, `m{`, `m}` (expand diagram).